# Chrome extension refreshes when dock/undock developer tool?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a chrome extension that works in a new tab in Google Chrome Developer Tool. When I dock/undock my  extension refreshes but other tabs does not.

How can I prevent refresh when I dock/undock devtool?

Comment: I highly doubt it's possible. Might be worth a feature request on the Chromium bug tracker.

Comment: I suppose that after docking/undocking once, your devtools page won't be reloaded again upon docking/undocking again. Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It always reload when I undock and dock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by updates of Google Chrome.